# Detect specifically a “failed to load script” ErrorEvent

Tags: javascript, error-handling, dom-events

How can an event handler for `error` discern whether this is a “the script failed to load” error?

When a `script` element specifies to load a script from a URL, but the script fails to load, the JavaScript engine [will dispatch an event with type `'error'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#notes) to that `script` element.

So an event handler can be written to catch this:

```js
    window.addEventListener('error', ((event) => {
        console.error('ErrorEvent:', event)
        document.documentElement.classList.add('load-fail')
    }), true)
```

Many other kinds of errors might cause an event of type `error` to be dispatched to that element. In that case treating it as “loading the script failed” is incorrect.

How can I write an event handler that can distinguish specifically “the script failed to load” errors, in a way that detects this for all standards-compliant browsers?